# What's the best way to unwrap tags with nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, unwrap

Say, I have a HTML file like so...

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>title</h1>
<p>So, help me <a href="/">remove</a> this.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What node method would I use to make it like so?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>title</h1>
<p>So, help me remove this.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

There's probably something like...

```rb
doc.css('a').each |i|
  i.unwrap
end
```

but I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#replace`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/73700b0ffeed0140677fb1fc282e7cc293c744b6/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb#L265) to replace the link tags with the text in them.

```rb
doc.css('a').each do |link|
  link.replace(link.inner_html)
end
```

Comment: Right, thank you. I could also probably monkey-patch in an unwrap method from that, I suppose.